# The Handler is not working properly in a function in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-handler

Following is a code which I wrote for increasing the brightness of the background color of some Views from 128 to 255 and vice-versa. Unfortunately, the handler which is supposed to make it wait is not functioning properly. Kindly help me with this code.

There is a 3x3 matrix having 9 views in it. I'm randomly changing the opacity of any one cell.

LEVEL      : Number of cells I want to change one by one.  Here, LEVEL : 3

color[9]   : 3x3 Matrix containing 9 Views.

```
public void pattern()  {

    for(int i=0;i<LEVEL;i++) {
        int rand= 0 + (int)(Math.random() * 8);
        computer+=rand;
        Log.d(" i :" , ""+i);
        Log.d(" random :" , ""+rand);
        Log.d("Pattern incoming " , ""+color[rand].getBackground().getAlpha());
        color[rand].getBackground().setAlpha(128);

        final int random=rand;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                color[random].getBackground().setAlpha(128);
                Log.d("Inside handler " , ""+color[random].getBackground().getAlpha());
                color[random].getBackground().setAlpha(255);
            }
        },2000);

        color[rand].getBackground().setAlpha(128);

        Log.d("Outside handler " , ""+color[rand].getBackground().getAlpha());

    }
}
```

**Android Monitor Logcat**

```
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ i :: 0
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ random :: 1
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Pattern incoming: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Outside handler: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ i :: 1
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ random :: 3
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Pattern incoming: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Outside handler: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ i :: 2
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ random :: 7
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Pattern incoming: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Outside handler: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ random :: 7
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Pattern incoming: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Outside handler: 128
$$ - 11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Inside handler: 128
$$ - 11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Inside handler: 128
$$ - 11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Inside handler: 128
```

As you can see that the "Inside handler" is printing at the end of the loop which runs for 3 times. I was expecting the "Inside handler" to execute just after the "Pattern incoming" and before "Outside Handler" in the following manner :

```
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ i :: 0
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ random :: 1
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Pattern incoming: 128
$$ - 11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Inside handler: 128    
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Outside handler: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ i :: 1
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ random :: 3
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Pattern incoming: 128
$$ - 11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Inside handler: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Outside handler: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ i :: 2
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/ random :: 7
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Pattern incoming: 128
$$ - 11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Inside handler: 128
11-06 04:21:27.267 30640-30640/com.example.aman D/Outside handler: 128
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see in the logcat? What do you mean the handler is not functioning properly? Also, please include it as a paste in the question so we can see it without having to open in a new window.

Comment: @DavidRawson. I've added the logcat statements here. I hope that the question is clear now. Your help will be highly appreciated .Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! That makes it easier to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you are getting in the logcat is as expected. Let's go through what you wrote:

(assume each statement takes 1ms)

```
1. first iteration of loop at time 1 ms
2. print "i :: 0"
3. print "random :: 1"
4. print "Pattern incoming :: 128"
5. post a task to the `Handler` to set the color 2 seconds from now (time 2005 ms)
6. print "Outside handler :: 128"
7. go on to next iteration of loop without waiting for the previous task to  complete 

8. second iteration of loop at time 8 ms:
9. print print "i :: 1"
10. print "random :: 3"
11. print "Pattern incoming :: 128"
12. post a task to the `Handler` to set the color 2 seconds from now (time 2012ms)
....
**loop terminates**
....
(finally a long time after the loop has completed the first scheduled task will be triggered)
....
2005. print "Inside handler: 128"
```

The loop doesn't wait for the `Handler` to complete the task before going on to the next iteration.

Your task now is to refactor your code so that you can get the effect you want. You will probably have to do some kind of iteration using code inside the `Handler`, rather than dumping a whole lot of tasks onto synchronously.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just realized my mistake. The application is working properly now. I did it using recursion. Calling the function within the handler itself worked perfectly.